# updating a line's data with d3.js in response to a drag event

Tags: d3.js

I'm using d3 to create two line graphs that can both be zoomed in when the user drags across a range of one of the graphs. I've been able to implement it by compeletely redrawing each graph at the end of the drag event, but I'd like to just do an update and possibly do an animated transition. For some reason, the graphs start to update, but they don't plot the new data, so they just become empty graphs instead, even when it's just one graph updating. I've done console.log(newdata) before and after the attempt to update, and there is plenty of data in the array, and it's formatted the same as the original data. I do have an awful lot of points (thousands), but I've seen d3 examples that handle such large datasets pretty well, at least as line graphs. Using Firebug, I get no errors, and the function completes (the rect gets removed). I realize I'll need to also update the scale, but I'd like to at least get the data updating first. I'm pretty new to d3, so I wouldn't be surprised if I were just doing something stupid. Any help much appreciated.

Here is the code that draws the line, followed by the code that handles the drag event.

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d){return x_scale(d.x)})
    .y(function(d){return y_scale(d.y)})
d3.select("#graph" + pointnum + " svg g")
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", line(data))
        .attr("class", "dist_line");

var dragrect;


var dragit = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on("dragstart", function(){
        omsi_globals.startx = Math.round(d3.mouse(this)[0]);
        dragrect = d3.select("#graph" + pointnum + " svg g")
            .append("rect")
                .attr("x", omsi_globals.startx)
                .attr("y", 0)
                .attr("width", 1)
                .attr("height", omsi_globals.chart_dimensions.height)
                .attr("fill", "gray")
                .attr("opacity", ".1");
    })
    .on("drag", function(){
        var currx = d3.mouse(this)[0];
        if(omsi_globals.startx > currx){
             dragrect.transition()
                .attr("x", currx)
                .attr("width", Math.abs(currx - omsi_globals.startx))
                .delay(0)
                .duration(10);
        }
        else dragrect.transition()
                .attr("width", Math.abs(currx - omsi_globals.startx))
                .delay(0)
                .duration(10);
    })
    .on("dragend", function(){
        var startx = omsi_globals.startx;
        var endx = Math.round(d3.mouse(this)[0]);
        //make sure the drag covered more than one pixel. If not, fade out the rect
        if(Math.abs(startx - endx)< 1){
            dragrect.transition().attr("width", 0); 
            return;
        }
        //people can drag both directions, so figure out which is lower and which is higher
        var lowerx = Math.min(startx, endx);
        var higherx = Math.max(startx, endx);
        //we'll scale as a proportion of the current x scale (not indices, which are more regular than the data)
        var currxmin = omsi_globals.d3data[pointnum-1][0].x;
        var currxmax = omsi_globals.d3data[pointnum-1][omsi_globals.d3data[pointnum-1].length-1].x;
        var chartwidth = omsi_globals.chart_dimensions.width;
        var newmin = ((lowerx/chartwidth) * (currxmax - currxmin)) + currxmin;
        var newmax = ((higherx/chartwidth) * (currxmax - currxmin)) + currxmin;
        //decide if it's time to switch to raw data or not
        var sourcedata = [];
        var newdata = [];
        //switch to raw data if down to less than threshold width
        if(newmax - newmin < omsi_globals.threshold) sourcedata = omsi_globals.plotpoints[pointnum-1].raw; 
        else sourcedata = omsi_globals.d3data[pointnum-1];
        for(i=0; i<sourcedata.length; i++){
            if(sourcedata[i].x < newmax && sourcedata[i].x > newmin){
                newdata.push(sourcedata[i]);
            }
        }
        //update the global variables to be read by d3
        omsi_globals.d3data[pointnum-1] = newdata;
        omsi_globals.d3xranges[pointnum-1] = [newdata[0].x, newdata[newdata.length-1].x];
        d3.selectAll("#graph" + pointnum + " path")
            .data(newdata)
            .transition()
            .duration(2500)
            .attr("d", line);
        dragrect.remove();

    });
```

Comment: Can you please build a jsFiddle representing your problem?

Comment: @ChrisJamesC, Thanks for taking a look. Here is a JSFiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/sH9wT/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/sH9wT/2/)

Comment: I've found a solution on my own, though I'd still appreciate more elegant solutions than mine. It seems I needed to define a new line with new scales and then update the path to use that. I'm guessing that has something to do with the fact that I have datasets of different sizes.